# How can I improve the seemingly capped framerate of my flash game?

Tags: flash, frame-rate

I used to be sure that all Flash games are capped to 30fps as [Edmund McMillen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_McMillen)'s  The Binding of Isaac runs at that frame rate. [N](http://www.thewayoftheninja.org/n_downloads.html) `v2.0` (Flash Player 11) runs at 60fps.

Why do games developed in Flash seem to have capped frame rate?
What are the limits on the fps when developing in Flash?

Comment: I don't understand why this question got 3 downvotes. It's a valid question. Even though questions about Flash are mostly relevant for historic reasons.

Comment: @Philipp "Does not show any research effort". (It's also not very useful --  a more useful question would have been something like "how can I change the framerate of my flash game".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to AS3 documentation:

> frameRate:
>
> Gets and sets the frame rate of the stage. The frame rate is defined as frames per second. By default the rate is set to the frame rate of the first SWF file loaded. Valid range for the frame rate is from 0.01 to 1000 frames per second.
>
> Note: An application might not be able to follow high frame rate settings, either because the target platform is not fast enough or the player is synchronized to the vertical blank timing of the display device (usually 60 Hz on LCD devices). In some cases, a target platform might also choose to lower the maximum frame rate if it anticipates high CPU usage.

[flash.display.Stage.frameRate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate)

Answer (score 2):

Flash Player has frame rate capped to 60, ignoring `Stage.frameRate` = 1000 property since FP10. In `Flash Player 9.0c`, both frame rate and timer resolution can be set to 1000 (millisecond-accurate).

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, the max. framerate has been extended to **120 fps**

Comment: Welcome GDSE & thanks for contributing. Based on your profile info, it seems like you have experience developing in Flash; this answer could be improved by sharing how/when the framerate can be increased to 120fps.